# is this a descriptive sentence "one should not dismiss an argument by pointing out the arguer's behavior."

Tags: comparison

There are two sentences from an LSAT question, whose task is to pick a sentence that is most similar to this model sentence:

"*In response to an argument, drawing attention to the arguer's behavior is irrational.*"

The answer sentence is "*one should not dismiss an argument by pointing out the arguer's behavior.*"

Even though the task is to pick the most similar, but I felt the above two sentences are clearly mismatched: the first one is descriptive, the other prescriptive. Or, is it because the answer sentence can be read as a descriptive?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks correct.  As you say the first sentence is descriptive, but if you describe something as negative you imply that you should not do it.

> Eating this mushroom will make one sick.

Implies

> One should not eat this mushroom.

So a purely descriptive sentence can have a prescriptive implication.

Comment: thank you so much! A quick follow-up: does a prescriptive sentence entail a descriptive implication?